# Google Cloud Storage API Without Authorization is Possible?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I am implementing cloud storage api in php for uploading mp3 files and loading those in site. 
I want to upload the files without authorization dialog is that possible? is there any sample without oauth2?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do? Do you want to provide a tool for users of a website to upload MP3 files to your bucket, provide a tool for users to upload MP3 files to buckets that they own, or write a system for your program to directly upload MP3 without a user's involvement?

Comment: Yes a tool to upload and want to use authentication using service, but i am unable.

Comment: You cannot upload files in a user's name without displaying an authorization dialog at least once. You can do this with your own account by using a service account. Alternately, you can request that the user grant offline access, so that your app will have the ability to work with the user's files when the user is not present.

Answer (score 2):

Everything going to cloud storage needs auth key.  You can set up a service account get a bearer key without the user logging in.  I modified some code from google-api-php-client.  To provide the bearer key.  Using the following.

function getMediaKey(){

```
/************************************************
  Make an API request authenticated with a service
  account.
 ************************************************/
set_include_path("../google-api-php-client/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';

$client_id = '<your clientid>';
$service_account_name = '<serviceaccountemail';
$key_file_location = '< location of you privatekey.p12>';

//echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");
if ($client_id == '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>'
    || !strlen($service_account_name)
    || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
}

$client = new Google_Client();

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'),
    $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$bearerKey = $client->getAccessToken();

return $bearerKey;
```

}

Then you can post your media files using the bearer key.
checkout https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/
Try it for examples